# Is it possible to use an ES6 class as a Typescript type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What I am trying to do is the following:

- Creating a Typescript class and exporting it in a .ts file.
- Compiling that .ts file into a ES6 .js bundled file.
- Importing the class from the bundled .js file in a new .ts file elsewhere.
- Using this imported class from the bundled file as a type.

Is this possible? if so, how could I achieve that?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to compile the original class into a `.js` file and use the class, defined inside the imported file, as a type inside another `.ts` file (most likely in another project?). I guess that's doable. What you need is a `.d.ts` file which defines the types. Those files can be created automatically (e.g. when creating a "library")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json` file. You can set a compiler option called [declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to `true`. Then when you compile your TS files to JS, it will automatically create the definition files for you (`.d.ts`). With those files, you can import them anywhere in your TS/JS project with type assertion.

**Edit**
`tsconfig.json` from my [project](https://github.com/MutterPedro/digjoy) as example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noUnusedLocals":  true,
    "incremental": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "dist/.tsBuildInfoFile",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test/**/*"]
}
```