# Built library cannot be imported in other project

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0, tsc, type-declaration

I need to build a library that's a wrapper for a soap API. The structure of the library is as follows:

```
|-node_modules
|
|-src
|  |-soapWrapperLibrary.ts
|  |-soapLibraryClient.ts
|
|-types
|  |-soapResponseType.d.ts
```

The `library` uses the `client`, which returns an object `soapResponseType` that I've defined.

This library will be used in another intern project. Nothing needs to be pushed to npm or similars. I've tried to compile it with `tsc` but the result of the compilation ignored the type that I've defined (soapResponseType.d.ts). That leads to an error while importing my library, because the definition file cannot be found.

I've tried several approaches that relates to the compiled types with `typeRoots`, with no result.

I expect from `tsc` that all my files are compiled as one bundle or something that can be imported as a whole, with types and classes in it.

With the following options, the only thing that I get is the next structure, without a trace of the soapResponseType.d.ts:

```
|-dist
|  |-lib
|  |  |-soapWrapperLibrary.js
|  |  |-soapWrapperLibrary.js.map
|  |  |soapLibraryClient.js
|  |  |soapLibraryClient.js.map
|  |-types
|  |  |-soapWrapperLibrary.d.ts
|  |  |soapLibraryClient.d.ts
```

The command `tsc --listFiles` shows the three files that I have created: two `.ts` files and one `.d.ts`

A repo for reproduction https://github.com/TheoSl93/buildLibraryTest

Those are my `tsconfig.json` and `package.json`:

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module":"es2015",
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist/lib",
    "declarationDir": "dist/types",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./types"
      ]
    },
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017", "dom"],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "types/*"
    ]
  },
  "typedocOptions": {
    "mode": "modules",
    "out": "docs",
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "test/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "test"
  ],
}
```

**package**

```
  "name": "soap-library",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "reproduce for stackoverflow",
  "main": "dist/lib/soapLibraryClient.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/TheoSl93/buildLibraryTest.git",
  "author": "Theo Sloot",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rm -rf dist",
    "build": "tsc --module commonjs"
  },
  "sideEffects": false,
```

At this point:

- Is there any way to include self-made definitions in the compiled using only `tsc`?
- Is it actually necessary? Can this library being imported using only the `.ts` files instead of the compiled `.js` files?

Comment: I guess this will answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681908/is-it-possible-to-use-an-es6-class-as-a-typescript-type/59683033#59683033

Comment: @PedroMutter not really, but thanks! The .d.ts files of my classes are generated as expected in `dist/types`, the one that I'm missing is the definition that I already made in my src `soapResponseType.d.ts`. I need that file in my `dist` folder

Answer (score 0):

To get typescript to use your type definition file (`soapResponseType.d.ts`), you need to define `soapResponseType.d.ts` as `soapResponseType.ts` in your types folder and it'll generate `soapResponseType.d.ts` with the exact content of `soapResponseType.ts` since both are `.ts` files and no transpilation is needed. Also, you should consider moving your `types` folder into `src` folder because your tsconfig is configured to only compile the `src` folder.